# GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords() draws with wrong colors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The attached picture sums it up. On the right is what I want. On the left is what I get. The colors are wrong. (left face image is from a captured screenshot from the game running in Unity. right face image is me pasting the correct art on top of the screenshot for comparison's sake)

The code I'm calling from `OnGUI()` to overlay the face image:

```
GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(toRect, texture, fromRect);
```

The texture in question comes from a 1024x1024 PNG saved from Photoshop. This PNG has the right colors in it when I open it, but not when `DrawTextureWithTexCoords` renders it to screen. I've experimented with different Photoshop export settings and texture import settings, but to no avail. It would be nice if I missed something there, but I seem to have run out of knobs to twiddle.

For troubleshooting purposes, I dragged the texture into the scene, applying it as a material to a surface of a mesh. The texture displayed with correct, original colors on the mesh. (Note - this is not the thing I'm trying to do. I need the texture to appear in GUI, not in-scene.)

There is no code that I know of that is processing the texture or doing something that would affect the rendering. I tried turning off my post-processing as a test, but it doesn't affect GUI.

This is running Unity 2019.1.13f1 on a 2015 IMac. I've also included a shot of the Inspector on the texture import settings below. And the *almost* original texture PNG (watermark added).

How can I get the face art to render with the correct colors?

[image: Showing difference in colors]
[image: Texture inspector]
[image: Texture PNG]

Comment: Can you provide the inspector values for the imported asset? The filtering and format?

Comment: I absolutely will, and thanks for asking. It will take me a little time to come back to it -

Comment: Additionally, if you just drag the texture asset into the scene, does it display correctly? Or does it look the same as with DrawTexture?

Comment: @ErikOverflow, I've edited the question to include the info you asked about. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the PNG file as well? I doubt it's the resize algorithm or settings. Is there any other script that is modifying this texture (not the drawn image, but the texture itself)? Like lightening it, desaturating, etc? @Erik Hermansen

Comment: @ErikOverflow I've shared the texture PNG. There is no script that is modifying the texture that I know of. I haven't written any code like that, and I'm pretty aware and cautious of of 3rd party assets added into the project that might have unexpected effects.

Comment: Where are you calling Gui.DrawTextureWithCoords? Update? Or onGUI?

Comment: It is called in onGUI(). Updating question to include that.

Comment: Try using Update() :D

Comment: Hmm, there is an error when I try to call `GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords()` from outside of `OnGUI()`. But following the spirit of your suggestion, I'm seeing what happens when I recode to use `Graphics.DrawTexture()`.

Comment: OnGUI calls many many many times per frame. I don't know if that's the actual cause, but it could be as simple as multiple renderings on the same frame oversaturating the colors.

Comment: @ErikOverflow, here is a "thank you" video showing the solution's end result. https://www.twitch.tv/videos/490240921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Answering my own question for posterity's sake.

I replaced the original code:

```
GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(toRect, texture, fromRect);
```

...with:

```
Graphics.DrawTexture(toRect, texture, fromRect, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This fixed the issue. The code above is called from `OnGUI()`, and behaves exactly like the original code but with corrected colors.

@Erik Overflow, in addition to other helpful comments, pointed out that `OnGUI()` is called many times per frame. So I'll consider refactoring the above to a call from `OnPostFrame()` for the sake of performance.

Comment: Do you mean "The code above is called from Update()"?

Comment: No, it is called from `OnGUI()`.